# How do i load my html files into the internet?

Tags: html

I am learning the html course from the available tutorials on the internet. And with that knowledge I have developed some html files and I believe there is more to go. These files consist of our old school friends and their present condition and what they're doing. I have created a bunch of html files. Like I have created a website for now named as www.mypage.com

```
         <a href="d:\mool.txt"> Arjun</a>
```

So in the href I'm just giving the path but those files are in my desktop pc itself. How do I put them on internet and share with my friends who are living somewhere out of this town. I want to reunite all of my school friends using these files. But where do I upload them and make it like a webiste to my friends? Is there any free way to do that? Or any possible way to reach it.

And I'm saying sorry if the question is not for the tag I mentioned. Please let me know and I remove the tag. I don't know what is the link to wikiposts to share my views. If you know then let me see the link. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote but sure one day Iam gonna hit the internet with a website www.mypage.com Thats my desire . It came to my mind when i was at 16 is to reunite all the old friends and every other stuff not a social network but something more than that.Thanks for your appreciation.

Comment: You do realize that domain is taken, right? ;)

Comment: Is that taken oh man then i would try for the better one !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Find a web hosting service (Google knows lots)
2. Sign up
3. Follow their instructions

> `<a href="d:\mool.txt"> Arjun</a>`

And use [relative uris](http://htmlhelp.com/faq/html/basics.html#relative-url)

Comment: Could you suggest one please?

Comment: @niko If you're looking for something free to start out with: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_web_hosting_services I don't us any of them though and never have. So no recommendation. Otherwise, then Google is your friend.

Comment: No, the hosting services I use are high end and probably cost a lot more then you would be comfortable paying.

Comment: Ok i will try those on google for more information and Thank for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I use http://webhosting.uk.com ... for about £32 a year you get asp.net hosting and access to sql server.

then you simply ftp up to your website something like this (using windows explorer) ....

ftp://mysite.com <-- not a real link

... that would then open up the remote server as if it was a local folder so you could drag and drop your files straight over.

there's an online chat link on the top right of the homepage, the support staff will walk you through getting setup.

don't forget though ... the cost of the domain name that's the bit that turns your server ip address in to stuff like google.co.uk ... I highly recommend them.

Answer (score 1):

I shall just expand on Quentin's answer, because it is clear that you are new.
What you need is a web hosting service. This is a service which hosts your html pages, meaning stores them in their own computers, and also displays them to the world as webpages. Web hosting services are usually paid, but there are some excellent free services if your content is not too big. A simple and free service that I would recommend is [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com). You could also try [Google App Engine](http://appengine.google.com), where you have more freedom and control over your content, but for the same reason it is a little more advanced. But since you are learning html, I believe it is a wise idea to learn more about these services and related concepts.
When you upload your files, the html links need to be changed. They can no longer point to files in your hard drive. When you upload these files, there will be a directory structure in it. All you need to do is place hyperlinks with relative addresses. 
And about what your website will be called, www.whatever.com, that is quite another business. For that, you need to register your own domain name, for which you **must** pay. If you don't want to, then your website will be labelled something under the hosting service domain name. This forum is not adequate to go into a more elaborate explanation of all this, but I  think I have mentioned all the key terms, so do some research!

Comment: Thank you I think i should first go with google.Yes you gave me some key words.